# Google Cloud Storage for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I need to do to my iOS app skillfully load data in Google Cloud Storage. Example: the user clicks to share a photo, select a photo and send it to the server, Google Cloud Storage. Then you need to get the name of a photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has actually already written a document explaining this for you.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/google-integration

You can accept the Google Cloud Storage API using either JSON or XML.  They even have sample libraries for everything except iOS.  But you could easily connect to the endpoints using simple HTTP requests from your iOS app or build a more robust wrapper.

Here is an example specifically about images
https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-application-solutions/#serving-and-processing-images

Comment: Thank you! I try today make this.